# Excel - Conditional format for range if range sum exceed the value of a cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In My sheet `Cell C7` has the value. when the sum of the range `K7:N7` (data entry fields) exceed/less than the value of `C7` then range `K7:N7` shows the red fill color.

I used `=$C$7<>SUM($K$7:$N$7)` , and it works fine. Here the problem is How do I copy this conditional format to the ranges `O7:R7` , `S7:V7` etc...

Copy `FormatPainter` also not helpful.

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Just copy and paste only format or go to manage conditional formats and apply it to where you want

Comment: If you want to compare C7 to the sum of O7:R7, then C7 to the sum of S7:V7, then you cannot simply copy/paste. You will have to create a new conditional formatting or create a more complex formula.

Comment: Yes. I agree `@Jerry` .